# C - array count, strtok, etc

Tags: c

i have a little problem on my code...

HI open a txt that have this:

LEI;7671;Maria Albertina da silva;xxxx@gmail.com;
9;8;12;9;12;11;6;15;7;11;
LTCGM;6567;Artur Pereira Ribeiro;fdsdfsd@gmail.com;
6;13;14;12;11;16;14;
LEI;7701;Ana Maria Carvalho;asasssas@gmail.com;
8;13;11;7;14;12;11;16;14;

---

LEI, LTCGM are the college;
7671, 6567, 7701 is student number;
Maria, Artur e Ana are the students name;
xxxx@gmail.com, ...@gmail are emails from students;
the first number of every line is the total of classes that students have;
after that is students school notes;

example:

College: LEI
Number: 7671
Name: Maria Albertina da Silva
email: xxxx@gmail.com
total of classes: 9
Classe Notes: 8 12 9 12 11 6 15 7 11.

My code:

```
typedef struct aluno {
    char sigla[5];//college
    char numero[80];//number
    char nome[80];//student name
    char email[20];//email
    int total_notas;// total of classes
    char tot_not[40]; // total classes
    char notas[20];// classe notes
    int nota; //class notes
    char situacao[80]; //situation (aproved or disaproved)
} ALUNO;

void ordena(ALUNO*alunos, int tam)//bubble sort
{

    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    char temp[100];
    for (i=0;i<tam;i++)
        for (j=0;j<tam-1;j++)
            if (strcmp( alunos[i].sigla[j], alunos[i].sigla[j+1])>0)
            {
                strcpy(temp, alunos[i].sigla[j]);
                strcpy(alunos[i].sigla[j],alunos[i].sigla[j+1]);
                strcpy(alunos[i].sigla[j+1], temp);
            }
} 

void xml(ALUNO*alunos, int tam)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char linha[60];//line
    int soma, max, min, count;//biggest note and lowest note and students per course count
    float media; //media of notes
    fp=fopen("example.txt","r");
    if (fp==NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        while (!(feof(fp)))
        {
            soma=0;
            media=0;
            max=0;
            min=0;
            count=0;
            fgets(linha,60,fp); 
            if (linha[0]=='L')
            {
                if (ap_dados=strtok(linha,";"))
                {
                    strcpy(alunos[i].sigla,ap_dados);//copy to struct

                    // i need to call bubble sort here, but i don't know how

                    printf("College: %s\n",alunos[i].sigla);
                    if (ap_dados=strtok(NULL,";"))
                    {                    
                        strcpy(alunos[i].numero,ap_dados);//copy to struct
                        printf("number: %s\n",alunos[i].numero);    
                        if (ap_dados=strtok(NULL,";"))
                        { 
                            strcpy(alunos[i].nome, ap_dados);//copy to struct
                            printf("name: %s\n",alunos[i].nome);    
                            if (ap_dados=strtok(NULL,";"))
                            {  
                                strcpy(alunos[i].email, ap_dados);//copy to struct
                                printf("email: %s\n",alunos[i].email);  

                            }   
                        }   
                    }   
                }
                i++;   
            }   
            if (isdigit(linha[0]))
            {
                if (info_notas=strtok(linha,";"))
                {
                    strcpy(alunos[i].tot_not,info_notas);
                    alunos[i].total_notas=atoi(alunos[i].tot_not);//total classes
                    for (z=0;z<=alunos[i].total_notas;z++)
                    {
                        if (info_notas=strtok(NULL,";"))
                        {
                            strcpy(alunos[i].notas,info_notas);
                            alunos[i].nota=atoi(alunos[i].notas); // student class notes
                        }
                        soma=soma + alunos[i].nota;
                        media=soma/alunos[i].total_notas;//doesn't work
                        if (alunos[i].nota>max)
                        {
                            max=alunos[i].nota;;//doesn't work
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (min<alunos[i].nota)
                            {
                                min=alunos[i].nota;;//doesn't work
                            }
                        }
                        //now i need to count the numbers of students in the same college, but doesn't work
                        /*If(strcmp(alunos[i].sigla, alunos[i+1].sigla)=0){
                         count ++;
                         printf("%d\n", count); here for LEI should appear 2 students and for LTCGM appear 1, don't work
                         }*/
                        //Now i need to see if student is aproved or disaproved
                        // Student is disaproved if he gets 3 notes under 10, how can i do that? 

                    }
                    printf("media %d\n",media); //media
                    printf("Nota maxima %d\n",max);// biggest note 
                    printf("Nota minima %d\n",min); //lowest note
                }
                i++;
            }  
        }    
    }    
    fclose(fp);    
}    

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ALUNO alunos;
    FILE *fp;
    int tam==3;

    fp=fopen("example.txt","r");
    alunos = (ALUNO*) calloc (tam, sizeof(ALUNO));
    xml(alunos,nomeFicheiro, tam);
    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Don't hide the description in the code. It would also make it easier to talk about your code if you'd use english identifiers

Comment: Formatting your code properly would help to make it a lot more readable and much easier to debug

Comment: Also, you're missing various required #includes, e.g. <stdio.h>, <string.h> - are these missing in the original code, or did you just neglect to copy/paste them ?

Comment: C with Portuguese variable names and English comments.  Now I have seen it all :-)

Comment: I have now taken the liberty of cleaning up the code and formatting it to make it legible.

Comment: One problem seems to be that `tam` is never initialised, and you're using it to determine how much memory to allocate ???

Comment: There is no question here.   The post does not describe what is failing, any error messages shown or erroneous results, and does not ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call bubble sort, why won't

```
ordena(alunos, tam);
```

work? (*Hint*: where is the *contiguous* memory where you store an entire *sequence* of records?)

(Hint #2: does it make sense to try to sort before you have read in *all* the records?)

By the way, I urge you most strongly to **indent your code to make it readable**.  Not only will you get a better grade, but it will make it easier to help you.  I'm pretty confident that the call I suggest won't work, but because almost all your code is in the left margin, I'm not sure.

You also might want to ask what are the different tasks here (read one record, read all records, sort all records, print records from a single colleage) and see if you can't find a way to organize your code such that you are using one of the available language constructs to separate one task from another.  (I'm being deliberately cryptic because I don't know what you've yet to study.  You should definitely ask your instructor or teaching assistant about this question.)

I think you also might wish to consider whether your bubble sort is doing the right thing.  I suggest you "play computer" by executing your code by hand on an example where `tam == 3`.